# I want to find A real valued function having a continuous first derivative for all points in domain, but with undefined higher order derivatives.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

A real valued function having a continuous first derrivative for all points in domain, but higher order derivatives are not even defined

Is there an example of such a function?

Comment: Take any continuous function not derivable and take then the integral of it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $g$ a continuous function with no derivative at any point and let $f(x)= \int_0^x g(t) dt$. Such function $g$ exists, the famous [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) is one of them.

Then $f'(x)=g(x)$ by the fondamental theorem of calculus but $f''(x)$ does not exist.